# Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно отправить массив с четырех цифр, допустим 0, 0, 0, 127 на python

Tags: c#, python, tcp-ip, qtcpsocket

Есть часть кода на С#, который отправляет по TCP/IP массив со значениями. Код прилагается.

```
    private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (!client.Connected)
        {
        }
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte userInput = Convert.ToByte(textBox2.Text);
        byte[] data = { 0, 0, 0, userInput };////   включение  на приемники побитно  

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        data = new Byte[256];
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            byte tr = data[i];
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(tr)+" ";
        }            
        textBox1.Text += "\r" + "\n";
    }
```

Пытался реализовать через zmq на python код ниже, но zmq не хочет отправлять массив значений.

```
     context = zmq.Context() 
     socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
     socket.bind("tcp://адрес:порт")
     socket.send([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

Как решить задачу чтобы отправить массив значений?

Comment: Отправить строку через пробелы

Comment: Самое простое - передавать данные через сепаратор (пробел например). Более сложные данные можно передавать например через JSON.

Answer (score 1):

У вас что-то странное написано на Python.

1. Клиентский сокет не нужно привязывать к какому-либо адресу. Система сама выберет подходящий адрес и порт при выполнении connect.
2. Массив байтов в Python представлен типом `bytes`, а вы используете список целых.

Вот как можно отослать четыре байта на Python:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("server", <port>))
s.send(bytes([0,0,0,127]))
```